# Testing VuexOrm with vue test utils and jest

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vuex-orm

this is my first question here. And my english is not to good. please forgive me for that. ;)

i need help for use vuexOrm with unit testing.
I will test an new model create with jest testing.

e.g. const user = new User - with a trigger

my mock is only return data.

My question. Is it possible to use the models in my mock or what is best practice?
Is it possible to use any mocks with VuexOrm and maybe someone has examples or tutorials somewhere?

Thank you

Comment: No one can help me? You need more information?